# How to implement a reduce correctly?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a table with data coming from an array, but there was some data that was repeated and I was advised to do a reduce.

The data arrives well, but there are some that I cannot obtain.

This is what I'm trying to implement, from what I understand about reduce, accumulate the array and then do the traversal

```js
this.headerVariedades = response['objParams'].monthlyTitle;
const aux = response['objParams'].monthlyDetail.reduce((acc, curr: {
  mesTemporada: string,
  codigo_producto: number,
  monto_moneda_norm: number
}) => {
  if (acc[curr.mesTemporada]) {
    acc[curr.mesTemporada][curr.codigo_producto] = curr.monto_moneda_norm;
  } else {
    const aux = {
      mesTemporada: curr.mesTemporada
    };
    aux[curr.codigo_producto] = curr.monto_moneda_norm;
    acc[curr.mesTemporada] = aux;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
this.listadoResultado = Object.values(aux);
```

[image: Tabla Resultado]

As seen in the image I need to fill in the "fecha" and "fecHas"

[image: Array]

This is what you get when you check with postman.

```
"weeklyTitle": [
        {
            "codigo": 27,
            "pro_des": "Maíz Amarillo, FOB Puerto Argentino",
            "gru_cod": 2
        },
        {
            "codigo": 18,
            "pro_des": "Maíz Yellow N° 2, FOB Golfo, USA",
            "gru_cod": 2
        },
        {
            "codigo": 51,
            "pro_des": "Maíz Yellow N° 3, FOB Golfo, USA",
            "gru_cod": 2
        }
    ],
    "weeklyDetail": [
        {
            "semana": 20,
            "temporada": 2021,
            "fecha": 1621224000000,
            "fecHas": 1621742400000,
            "codigo_producto": 18,
            "monto_moneda_norm": 305.4700
        },
        {
            "semana": 20,
            "temporada": 2021,
            "fecha": 1621224000000,
            "fecHas": 1621742400000,
            "codigo_producto": 27,
            "monto_moneda_norm": 259.8000
        },
        {
            "semana": 20,
            "temporada": 2021,
            "fecha": 1621224000000,
            "fecHas": 1621742400000,
            "codigo_producto": 51,
            "monto_moneda_norm": 304.4700
        },
        {
            "semana": 21,
            "temporada": 2021,
            "fecha": 1621828800000,
            "fecHas": 1622347200000,
            "codigo_producto": 18,
            "monto_moneda_norm": 299.3500
        },
        {
            "semana": 21,
            "temporada": 2021,
            "fecha": 1621828800000,
            "fecHas": 1622347200000,
            "codigo_producto": 27,
            "monto_moneda_norm": 254.3333
        },
        {
            "semana": 21,
            "temporada": 2021,
            "fecha": 1621828800000,
            "fecHas": 1622347200000,
            "codigo_producto": 51,
            "monto_moneda_norm": 298.3500
        }
    ],
```

In this way I am assembling the table, as I receive the header in another array I do a forEach.

```js
this.columnasGrilla.push({
  header: 'Semana ',
  field: 'semana'
});
this.columnasGrilla.push({
  header: 'Desde',
  field: 'fecha'
});
this.columnasGrilla.push({
  header: 'Hasta',
  field: 'fecHas'
});
this.headerVariedades.forEach((item) => {
  this.columnasGrilla.push({
    header: item.pro_des,
    field: 'item.codigo'
  })
})
```

This is the example that repeat values. This happens when I choose more variety of a product.
in this case I don't use the reduce . I just call it this way

```
this.listadoResultado = response['objParams'].weeklyDetail;
```

that's why I was recommended to use reduce to sort the table in these cases

[image: Tabla]

Comment: You should give your data and your expected result in the question that would help to find out where your problem is

Comment: edited, I add what postman returns and how I am assembling the table.

I also don't know if the correct thing is to accumulate by semana or fecha

Comment: What do you mean by *"there was some data that was repeated"*? Are you talking about duplicate data? If so, where/how/when does this occur? The data that you are currently showing, as well as the rendered page, don't show any duplicates.

Comment: That happens when I choose more than one variety of a product, that's why they recommended me to use reduce.

that's how i was doing it from the beginning:

`this.listadoResultado = response['objParams'].weeklyDetail;`